# how to stop UITextView to scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5, uitextview

I have a custom table with just three cells. In third cell I have a textView. The three cells cover up enough space on the screen so that just the keyboard space is left. I don't want anything to be movable or scrollable, so I used `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;`.

This is working fine with earlier version of iOS. However with iOS 5, it shows some weird behavior. When I enter multiple lines of text in textView the whole table scrolls up. Ideally the table should stick there and only textView should scroll.

After trying lots of things I found that the textView is placed so near to the keyboard (as the textView is placed in last cell and just below it is the keyboard) that the iOS tries to move the textView up, for which it scrolls the complete table up. Is there any way to stop this auto scroll of tableView.

I found the same problem mentioned here 
[Disable UITextView scrolling the containing view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883447/disable-uitextview-scrolling-the-containing-view)
however it is also not answered yet. And the workaround mentioned over there won't work for me as my containing view itself is scrollable (`UITableView`)

Comment: You find a solution to this? Running into the same problem.

Comment: @SteveBaughman: Not exactly. I did a workaround. the `UITextView` was too close to the keyboard due to which it was being shifted above. I increased the distance between the `UITextView` and the keyboard to resolve this issue. I am still looking for a proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

for me, i work around with scroll in table view like this

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y != 0)
    {
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a completely new subview on the fly. Add a `UITextView` to `self.view` and give it a frame that corresponds to the same position on the screen. The table view should not scroll now.

In case this does not work because `self.view` is the table view, change your controller into a class `UIViewController` and implement the delegate and datasource methods yourself (i.e. you have to mention them in the `@interface` declaration). The table view should then be a subview of `self.view` and you have to hook it up via IB.

Before you dismiss the keyboard, copy the content to your original text view.

Comment: I am adding the subview programmatically to the self.view on the fly, however its not working.

Changing my main view to `UIViewController` from `UITableViewController` is not the solution I am looking for. Since this problem started from iOS 5, I am sure there must be some property or method that can be set to stop auto scrolling.