# UITextView Inside UIScrollView Scrolling Parent as Text is Entered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a `UITextView`. As text is entered into the `UITextView` the `UIScrollView` will scroll to ensure that the text is entirely visible in the content frame. I don't want this.

I've disabled scrolling on the `UIScrollView`, however this has no effect. Anyone know how to stop this? A sample project can be found here: http://cl.ly/1P1u3y302r3q1f1C063K.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar issues with `UITextView`. It seems `scrollEnabled` property does not cancel autoscrolling. I have [solved](https://github.com/onegray/UITableKit/blob/master/TableKit/DefaultTheme/TKDefaultTextViewCellView.m) it by overriding `setContentOffset:` method.
The following `preventScrolling` flag might help:

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL preventScrolling;
@end

@implementation MyScrollView 
@synthesize preventScrolling;
-(void) setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(!self.preventScrolling) {
        [super setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:animated];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: It's better to override `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` (the message that's sent to UIScrollView from UITextView when its text property changes) to do nothing, so that you don't need to have an extra property.

Answer (score -1):

you have set the wrong *contentSize:* of scroll view....

always set the content size according to content inside scroll view, if content height and width is greater than scroll view height and width then only increase the content size else put it the same as its width and height of scroll view

```
[self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(4096, 4096)];
```

instead of it put this *contentsize:*

```
[self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(mainScrollView.frame.size.width, mainScrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

may this will help you